# queries in PSQL that gets info from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write queries from different tables, but there is one query that I am having an issue with. We are using PSQL to make these queries. The query that I am trying to execute is:

> For each country with at least one hundred cities in the database, list the total number of cities it contains. Order the results in ascending order of the number of cities.

I know I am going to have to use the count function to get the count of the cities, but I am confused on how to list the total number of cities. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
SELECT country.name AS name, COUNT(city.name) AS num_cities 
FROM what.country 
WHERE  (num_cities > 100) 
ORDER BY num_cities ASC
```

Here are the two tables that I am using:

```
              Table "what.country"
     Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
 continent       | continent             | not null
 region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
 surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
 indep_year      | smallint              | 
 population      | integer               | not null default 0


                 Table "what.city"
    Column    |         Type          |                     Modifiers                    
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id           | integer               | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(35) | not null default ''::character varying
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 district     | character varying(20) | not null default ''::character varying
 population   | integer               | not null default 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GROUP BY and HAVING as you need to get countries with at least 100 cities

```
    SELECT country.name AS name   
    COUNT(city.name) AS   
    num_cities 
    FROM country 
    JOIN city 
    ON country.country_code =
    city.country_code
    GROUP BY country.nam
    HAVING COUNT(city.name) >=100
    ORDER by COUNT(city.name) ASC
```